# Automatically resolving a symbol naming conflict using asdf and defpackage

Tags: common-lisp, asdf

I have defined a common lisp package using asdf which uses both parenscript and clsql.

But these packages have a naming conflict around the function GET-TIME. When the module is loaded I can resolve the conflict manually at the prompt (code may not be exact):

```
Select a symbol to be made accessible in package MY_PACKAGE:
   1. PS-JS-SYMBOLS:GET-TIME
   2. CLSQL-SYS:GET-TIME
```

I pick option 1.

What is the best way to modify my project so that this conflict is resolved automatically?

Do I modify the .asd file or the project.lisp file?

I think the answer might have something to do with [:shadowing-import-from](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defpkg.htm), but I don't really understand the examples given on that documentation page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @Rainer Joswigs answer above, the specific answer to my question was to write my defpackage form as follows:

```
 (defpackage #:my-package 
      (:use :cl :clsql :parenscript)
      (:shadowing-import-from :parenscript "GET-TIME")
      )
```

Answer (score 5):

*Packages*, *symbols*, *exporting*, *using*, etc. are a feature of Common Lisp, and not ASDF specific.

```
CL-USER 1 > (defpackage "FOO" (:use "CL") (:export "BAZ"))
#<The FOO package, 0/16 internal, 1/16 external>

CL-USER 2 > (in-package "FOO")
#<The FOO package, 0/16 internal, 1/16 external>

FOO 3 > (defun baz () 'FOO)
BAZ

FOO 4 > (defpackage "BAR" (:use "CL") (:export "BAZ"))
#<The BAR package, 0/16 internal, 1/16 external>

FOO 5 > (defun bar:baz () 'bar::bar)
BAR:BAZ

FOO 6 > (in-package "CL-USER")
#<The COMMON-LISP-USER package, 54/64 internal, 0/4 external>

CL-USER 7 > (defpackage "ZIPPY"
              (:use "FOO" "BAR")
              (:shadowing-import-from "BAR" "BAZ"))
#<The ZIPPY package, 1/16 internal, 0/16 external>

CL-USER 8 > (in-package "ZIPPY")
#<The ZIPPY package, 1/16 internal, 0/16 external>

ZIPPY 9 > (baz)
BAR::BAR
```